# Swift 3 - Setting variable in TableViewController swift file depending on cell clicked

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift3

I'm trying to set the a string depending on which cell in a tableView is clicked. The BlueLineTableViewController is the one which should capture the user's click.

```
import UIKit

class BlueLineTableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return bluelinestations.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bluelinecell", for: indexPath)

    let station = bluelinestations[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = station.name
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: station.image)
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let row = indexPath.row
    if row == 0 {
        BlueBelmontTableViewController().feed = "http://lapi.transitchicago.com/api/1.0/ttarrivals.aspx?key=mykey&mapid=40890&outputType=JSON"
    }
    if row == 1   {
        BlueBelmontTableViewController().feed="http://lapi.transitchicago.com/api/1.0/ttarrivals.aspx?key=mykey&mapid=40820&outputType=JSON"
    }
}
```

The BlueBelmontTableViewController's feed variable should change/be set to another url depending on which cell is clicked in the BlueLineTableViewController.

```
import UIKit

class BlueBelmontTableViewController: UITableViewController {

class Destinations {
    var destination: String = ""
    var time: String = ""
}

var feed = ""

var dataAvailable = false

var records = [Destinations]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    parseData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    for r in records {
        r.time = ""
        r.destination = ""
    }
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataAvailable ? records.count : 15
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if (dataAvailable) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let destinationRow = records[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = destinationRow.destination
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = destinationRow.time
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlaceholderCell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}

func parseData() {
    guard let feedURL = URL(string: feed) else {
        return
    }
    let request = URLRequest(url: feedURL)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {(data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("Error")
        }
        else {
            if let content = data {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: []) as? [String:Any] ?? [:]
                    print(json)
                    if let ctattimetable = json["ctatt"] as? [String:Any] {
                        if let estArrivalTime = ctattimetable["eta"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                            for item in estArrivalTime{
                                if let headingTowards = item["destNm"] as? String,
                                    let arrivalTime = item["arrT"] as? String {
                                    let record = Destinations()
                                    record.destination = headingTowards
                                    record.time = arrivalTime
                                    self.records.append(record)
                                }
                                self.dataAvailable = true
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch {
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
}
```

I've tried setting the url in the didSelectRowAt method depending on the indexPath.row as can be seen in BlueLineTableViewController, but it does not seem to do anything. Does anybody know how I would go about doing this?

Below is the Main.storyboard of this part of my project:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are not able to pass value because you are setting `feed` property to the completely new instance of `BlueBelmontTableViewController` not the one that is added in navigation stack using your `segue` that you have created from your `UITableViewCell` to `BlueBelmontTableViewController`.

What you need to do is override `prepareForSegue` in your `BlueLineTableViewController` to pass your value to `BlueBelmontTableViewController`.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as! BlueBelmontTableViewController
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
           vc.feed = "http://lapi.transitchicago.com/api/1.0/ttarrivals.aspx?key=mykey&mapid=40890&outputType=JSON"
        }
        if indexPath.row == 1   {
            vc.feed = "http://lapi.transitchicago.com/api/1.0/ttarrivals.aspx?key=mykey&mapid=40820&outputType=JSON"
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I had to do if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row for it to work but otherwise it works perfectly (and not sure if it matters but I made it into a switch statement instead, like switch index { case 0: vc.feed = "url" etc.

Comment: @moesyzlack23 Welcome mate :), Don't write like that check my edited answer and change your condition to `indexPath.row` and you all set to go

Comment: Ok thanks, it works! Just curious, is there a difference between the two implementations? It seems to work fine either way for me

Comment: @moesyzlack23 Both of is equal, but your one will go in optional chaining as of `indexPath` is optional so `row` also optional where as I have just checked for `indexPath`.

Comment: got it, you're the best!

Comment: @moesyzlack23 Glad you understand mate :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
BlueBelmontTableViewController().feed = "http://lapi.transitchicago.com/api/1.0/ttarrivals.aspx?key=mykey&mapid=40890&outputType=JSON"
```

use

```
self.feed = "http://lapi.transitchicago.com/api/1.0/ttarrivals.aspx?key=mykey&mapid=40890&outputType=JSON"
```

beacause BlueBelmontTableViewController() is initialing new instance of BlueBelmontTableViewController and you want to change the instance you already have so you should use self instead of creating new instance.